# Azure KeyVaultClient Secret for GetKey

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have this code snippet:

[image]

I need to get the parameters:

`keyIdentifier` is easy enough:

[image]

`clientId` is also easy to find:

[image]

`clientSecret` - where do I get this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot is of a Managed Identity, there is no client secret that you can use.
It uses certificates internally, but that is not really relevant here.

My recommendation would be to use the Azure.Identity library to acquire tokens with `DefaultAzureCredential`.
And also use the newer KeyVault libraries e.g.:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/4.1.0
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/4.1.0

`DefaultAzureCredential` can use a system-assigned Managed Identity automatically and your user account in local development environments.
It tries multiple approaches and uses the one that works.

Comment: What's the *simplest* way that I can authenticate to retrieve a key, between environments? I don't want to have to manage AD accounts, IAM, etc. (which I'm not very familiar with). I just need to get a key out of Azure, locally or when deployed. Is there not a simple credential I can pass which can be used across environments?

Comment: App registration in Azure AD, client id + client secret is probably the simplest, just add that app to Key Vault access policies and it's good to go. But it does involve you having to store the secret somehow securely. That's why my usual recommendation is Managed Identities in Azure and local user account in local environment (or user secrets in .NET Core) since with them there is no secrets that you need to manage. Also, based on your question you are returning some kind of signing key. Are you sure you want to use the same key across environments? Typically production keys are separate.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Right now the urgency to fix a broken website means I'm trying to find the simplest option, which I can properly implement later. It looks like an easier option is to have the app generate & store it's own X509 certificate if that doesn't exist - and avoid all these other dependencies (it might not be hosted in Azure shortly, too).